# AWS lambda does not send return to SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I try to send a message to an SNS topic after the lambda function is done.

For that I return from the lambda handler function the message (python).

Lambda executes without error and returns the message correctly. IAM is set to allow the lambda to publish to the specific SNS topic.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "None",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sns:Publish",
                "sns:Subscribe",
                "sns:ConfirmSubscription"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:123456789012:TOPIC"
        }
    ]
}
```

simplified code of lambda is:

```
#import packages

def handler(event, context) -> dict:
    """
    lambda handler function for invoking session

    param event: json/dict like key:val mapping for regular lambda invocations with custom topics (e.g. different data pipeline stage, different customers etc.)
    param context: AWS logging

    return: dict like key:val mapping to deliver custom topics to AWS Service invocations
    """

    #-----# key:val mapping #-----#
    '''
    '''
    Message = event["Records"][0]["Sns"]["Message"]
    Message = Message.replace("'", "\"")
    Message = json.loads(Message)

    #does lot's of stuff here
    #eg. getting data from S3, posting data to S3
    #send topic to SNS is NOT used, since it should be configured by the general lambda settings as endpoint destination.



    # -----# update key:val mapping #-----#
    event = {
        "timestamp": timestamp
    }

    return event
```

is there anything else one has to do? Because after inspecting cloudwatch logs, no messages arrive at the SNS.

Comment: How are you publishing the message to sns?

Comment: I tried to use the implemented lambda destination function. 
I have 2 destinations, one for failure, one for success. 
Failures are working and I directly receive the subscribed alarm topic.

Comment: You have both failure and success destinations allowed for publish in iam? Are some invocations going to failure destination and some missing, or just all going to failure destination? You could attempt to publish a test the message to each topic within your lambda using the sdk to verify the connection.

Comment: can you post your lambda code

Comment: theherk, yes. One policy for my Topic on failure. One policy for my Topic on Success.

Comment: And both policies attached to the role that the lambda executes with? Can you show the contents of the policies? Can you test the publish within your handler?

Comment: Both are attached and look exactly like the one postet. 
I tried to publish a message to the topic using boto3.client. This works well. 
What if I want to decouple it from code and send message via lambda config. Is this not possible at all?

Comment: Are you actually setting `event` to just the `timestamp` before returning? I'd think you'd just want to update that key. At any rate, you should be able to use these on success destination. And if you can publish to this same topic with boto3, you should be able to do so with lambda configuration. Now, I'm not positive that the full event is published in that case; it may be just the invocation record. But if this isn't working, there is probably something wrong with your destination configuration.

Comment: No. Event comes with more. I removed most for simplicity. Important is, it’s dict type. Maybe it has to return not as dict, but as string. If so, I am wondering why the type format is resulting to publish no message at all. 
I checked the message coming from boto3 it’s exactly as expected. But I still have no clue why it’s not working via lambda config directly

Comment: How are you invoking this lambda?

Comment: I ask because, you can only use these destinations with asynchronous invocations. Which means, you can't use the "test" button and expect it to work correctly, I believe, since that is synchronous.

Comment: You are correct. I tried by using `test` - it's not working with that way. Therefore I changed it now to invoke by another `SNS` and later in production it comes by `CloudWatch EventBridge`. 
Both ways are working now, the fault was to use test

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Used `Test` for testing, but it invokes the lambda function not async. Therefore the fault was in the kind of invokation.